# Page width is getting out after adding Urdu in Table

Tags: tables, xetex

When I am trying urdu in the table column it is going outside of the page width in latex this is my code of writing urdu inside the table

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{CHECKING OF URDU IN LATEX}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
s# & Type & Words \\
\hline
1 & Normal & \begin{urdu}
ریڈیو پاکستان کی عمارت کو لیز پر دینے کا حکومتی فیصلہ ’پچاس ارب کی پراپرٹی پر مندر تو نہیں بنا سکت

\end{urdu} \\
\hline
2 & Normal & \begin{urdu}
چائنیز سفیر اردو بڑی اچھی بولتا ہے عثمان بزدار کی مسکراہٹ سے اندازہ لگا لو
\end{urdu} \\

\hline
3 & Normal & \begin{urdu}
ہم آپ سے بہت پیار کرتے ہیں، لہذا ہم اس اردو کے غلط تحریر پر ہنس نہیں کرتے ہیں
\end{urdu} \\


\end{tabular}
\label{tab1}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You could use a `p{<width>}` type column instead of the `c` type column. An alternatie would be using `X` type columns from the `tabularx` package. Apart from that, please make your code a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: `c` columns are always single line, if you put that much text in then you force the table wide, this is unrelated to Urdu, you would see the same in any language.

Comment: Please consider using the right tags for your question. Like your earlier question, this question has nothing to do with `biblatex` and at least prima facie not a lot to do with `latex3`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you make an answer for this i will accept it

Comment: must be a duplicate, I'll find one...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle there are so many tables can you help me with which one i will refer

Comment: just change `ccc` to `llp{6cm}`  or whatever width you want for the third column,

Comment: it is giving Illegal character in array arg. \begin{tabular}{|l|l|p{2cm}]|}